# Create defined values for an Object

Tags: java

I'm trying to clean my code and I need a way to create an object/variable/class with defined values.

As for example I should create a simple object called myObject with two properties: North, South and use it like this:

```
switch(myObject){
case(myObject.North):
//doSomething
break;

case(myObject.South):
//doSomething
break;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an `enum`?

Comment: Exactly what I'm searching for, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [enum](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_enums.asp):

```
enum Direction { North, South }
Direction myObject = Direction.North;

switch(myObject) {
    case North:
    //doSomething
    break;

    case South:
    //doSomething
    break;
}
```

Comment: @khelwood you are right I just fixed that

Comment: please how to declare it as Public and access it from other classes?

Comment: @SteveRogers you can define `public enum Direction { North, South }` in its own file and just access it from another files like any other class

Comment: Please note that according to standard Java naming conventions, `enum` values should be in upper-case, i.e. `NORTH`, `SOUTH`.